# How to edit validation rules dynamically in Yii

Tags: php, validation, yii, yii-cmodel

I have a validation rules in my model:

```
public function rules()
{
  return array(){
   array('order', 'required'),
  }
}
```

I have an input text element in my order view:

```
input type="text" name="order1"
```

when I press a button, my input text element have increased, so now I have 2 input text element with different name. e.g:

```
input type="text" name="order1"
input type="text" name="order2"
```

My question is:
how can i edit validation rules dynamically, so when "order1" or "order2" is null, there are a validation message. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have different approach to the problem. Instead of having inputs with name = order1, order2, orderN, have an array like this `<input type="text" name="orders[]" />` And in the model, always expect array of orders, loop through it and if any of items does not validate, add an error.

```
class SomeModel
{
 public $orders;
 public function rules()
 {
  return array(
   array('orders', 'validateOrders'),
  );
 }

 public function validateOrders($attribute, $params)
 {
  foreach($this->orders as $order)
   if (empty($order)) {
    $this->addError('orders', 'There is an empty order');
    break;
   }
 }
}
```

The above code is written on the go here and is untested but should closely show my idea.

Comment: Thank you! I doesn't know that something like that is possible in Yii. I'm still beginner :)

Comment: You don't even need the brackets to be honest, it will become an array no matter what its called assuming there are two inputs with the same name.

Comment: That is correct. But explicitly writing the inputs like this is helpful for PHP developers to understand your intentions :)